# How to create Jenkins webhook for Dev repo to run automation in QA repor

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have an automation github repo.

1. Development team will create a new branch pull latest code and add new feature and push updated code to `Develop` branch.
2. From QA side, I need to create webhooks which will `check the new PR raised`, and then `pull the branch from which PR is raised`.
3. Then I need to build the app and run it, and from QA repo, I need to run sanity test.

My question is : I have seen I can add only one repo in Jenkins, so I add QA repo. Now to do webhook from Dev repo, where I need to add details and how I add dev repo details.

Please help

Comment: Whenever you raise a PR in develop branch, you could create a webhook which listens for such events and triggers a jenkins build from your develop branch and also trigger a QA jenkins Job ( Passing branch name parameter, of the pull request branch).

Now your QA will take latest pull of that branch in QA jenkins job and run sanity checks for the same. And if QA jenkins fails, you mark the build as unstable.